# How to set a PHP SESSION_ID using a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, session

I'm trying manage my users PHP SESSIONS using a MySQL database. I am setting the SESSION_ID() manually using the ID primary key field in the database so its unique to each user.

The API i have created is trying to retrieve the CustomerID session variable to be able to set the SESSION_ID however the SESSION_ID isnt set yet so I'm stuck in a loop.

The outcome is to get the users profile pic to be displayed

Here is the funtion to hoepfully make a little more sense... (I'm using Slim PHP framework)

```
$app->get('/api/getprofilepic', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    session_id($resultsess);
    session_start();

    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect(); 

     $sqlsess =  "SELECT SessionID FROM sessions WHERE CustomerID= {$_SESSION['CustomerID']} LIMIT 1";

    $stmtsess = $db->query($sqlsess);
    $resultsess = $stmtsess->fetchColumn();




    $sql =  "SELECT ProfilePic FROM login WHERE CustomerID= {$_SESSION['CustomerID']}";


        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

The issue is obvious, the "$resultsess" isnt defined yet as i have not run the query however i need to set the sessionID before i run the query in order to get the sessionID.

If there is an easier way of doing this, please let me know.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Is there some reason that standard cookie methods won't work for storing the session ID?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'm not entirely sure how they work. I've tried to just use native PHP sessions but I have issues with that too as it is creating a new SESSION file everytime a API function is called

Comment: Well, as you've found, you need to get the session ID in order to look up the current user, so it's not possible to get it based on the current user: chicken and egg problem. The only solutions I'm aware of are to store the session ID in a cookie and read it back as required, or to include the session ID in the URL. You'll need to do some reading on both options to see which is more appropriate for you, and how to implement it in your system.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you for your time on this Greg, I'm currently looking into cookies at the moment. Think that may be my solution :)

Comment: It's by far the more common option. There should be tons of articles about it. A quick Google indicates that Slim includes middleware specifically for this, so it should more or less be a plug-and-play change for you.